# Confused by suspend function in coroutines and thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin-coroutines

In Android, I usually see some code snippet of suspend functions like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch { //implemented by Person1
    A()
}

//implemented by Person2
suspend fun A() {
    B()
}

//implemented by Person3
suspend fun B() {
    C()
}

//implemented by Person4
suspend fun C() {
    doSomething()
}
```

If Person3 may write like below to let C() running on the different thread

```
suspend fun B() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        C()
    }
}
```

What is the Person2 who is responsible for A() also think since he is calling suspend function B, so he need to let B running on a thread.

This may create multiple threads which is not necessary, so how to let the Person1 and Person2 know the suspend function he calls is already running on the different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume `doSomething` accesses the file system. It's then the responsibility of that function to move those parts on the IO dispatcher. The function could look like this:

```
suspend fun doSomething() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // accesses the file system here
}
```

The caller of `doSomething`, function `C`, does not need to know about the file system access and which dispatcher the function is executed on. It can simply call `doSomething()` and everything is fine.

Now, let's assume `B` decides to call `C` like this:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    C()
}
```

The current coroutine will be moved from the current thread to a thread of the IO dispatcher and `C` is called. `C` then calls `doSomething` and that function now also executes `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. But the coroutine already *is* on that dispatcher, so no additional thread switches happen. Then, the file system access occurs. On a thread of the IO dispatcher, as `B` aswell as `doSomething` made sure of.

`withContext` doesn't create a new coroutine that would occupy a new thread. Instead, the *current* coroutine is configured in a way that it runs on the appropriate thread - but if it already *is* running on the correct thread, nothing changes, no new threads are occupied. You can call `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` any number of times, only the first one actually has an effect.

This is different from launching a new coroutine with `launch` or `async`. That may very well lead to the dispatcher creating a new thread (or reusing one from the thread pool). But that's what suspend functions are for: When you already *are* in a suspend function, no new coroutine is needed to call the next suspend function. No new threads are involved.

To conclude, it is not necessary that `B` switches to the IO dispatcher, but it also does no harm. But the documentation of `doSomething` and `C` could confirm that the internals make sure the file system access is moved to the IO dispatcher. That way `B` wouldn't have to guess if everything is handled correctly and if `B` should, just to make sure, move the current coroutine to the IO dispatcher itself.

Comment: Thank you. I understand only suspend fun doSomething need to be dispatched to other thread and all other suspend function like A B C doesn't have to care about the thread.  But if the situation is reversed, what if the developer of doSomething forgot to use withContext(Dispatchers.IO), this may make func A and B and C running on the main thread, so how to prevent this situation happens?

Comment: A, B and C will always run on the main thread, independent of what doSomething does. A function only runs on a different dispatcher if the function itself or any of its callers (up in the call stack) moved the coroutine to another dispatcher. doSomething, however, is *down* in the call stack. What happens there has no effect on the functions higher up in the call stack. So, if doSomething doesn't move the coroutine to a specific dispatcher it always uses the same dispatcher as the caller. In that case the caller can decide to move itself (and therefore also doSomething) to the IO dispatcher.